# What's the kind of job that c/java can do but PHP will be hard to do?

Tags: java, php, c

Here,job is something like a complete utility.

I need to know this to start the c/java journey!

Comment: Something like a complete utility. Glad you explained it so well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to differenciate between C and Java as well.
With C you can go in-depth into system-close programming. You could develop hardware drivers, operation systems and much more whereas you will not be able to do this in Java. Java runs in a virtual machine and therefore has no direct access to system-close operations.

PHP is best suited for web-programming but can also be used offline. You could use PHP for pretty much the same as you could use Java but it isn't actually meant for this. PHP is intended to be used on web-servers. So it is generally said easier to write desktop-applications in Java or C.

Concluding:

- C: System-close operations as well as desktop applications
- Java: Desktop applications, web-services, pretty much everything
- PHP: server-side-applications

Comment: Actually, you CAN develop device drivers, operating systems and stuff like that in Java.  For example http://jnode.org

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know that :)
But this is of course rather a very special case and a proof-of-concept than a usual job for java